# No wifi with xubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron 8600

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, xubuntu, dell

I've just installed Xubuntu 12.04 on an old Dell Inspiron 8600 laptop, because of the lack of a pae, and everything works fine except wifi.

I've followed the instructions on [the Wifi help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) and have installed the b43legacy driver as directed, but it's not working.

I've tried removing the `bcmwl` driver package, but it's not installed.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Its: 02:03.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4309 802.11abg Wireless Network Controller [14e4:4324] (rev 03)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device does not require b43legacy. Please get a temporary wired ethernet or other internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I think I've tried that but I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working. It took a combination of your suggestion and turning on the WiFi using the function key.